what is the meaning of the expression '' matters of consequence ''?
The full text is from the story of The Little Prince:

In the course of this life I have had a great many encounters with a great many people who have been concerned with matters of consequence.

please explain that what the meaning of matters of consequence is and give me some synonym at the end.

They are matters which are not inconsequential. Please use a dictionary when posting as we ask the partiipants show they have made an effort. Also, please see the Help section, top right, last icon.

[Please explain what X is. and not: Please explain what is X. That's for your notes. ]

Before asking about the meaning of a word or phrase, please check a dictionary or two. Then, if you don't understand what you find, you can ask about the misunderstanding.

Matters of consequence could be understood as important matters - things that are not inconsequential.
Collins defines "of consequence" as something or someone of consequence is important or valuable. If something or someone is of no consequence, or of little consequence, they are not important or valuable.
You can add this adjective phrase to almost anything, but "matters of consequence" is something of an idiom and appears in the title of various works including books, plays and movies.

matter of consequence are consequential matters.
The preposition of in "noun1 of noun2" constructions  often has the function of attributing noun2 to noun1 as one of its salient properties; such constructions can be paraphrased by turning noun2 into an adjective  and placing it before noun1:

matters of consequence

consequence noun  becomes consequential adjective, and the adjective is placed before noun1:

consequential matters

That which is consequential has consequences, and to say that something has consequences is  a way of implying that  it is not irrelevant but important.
